# Changing tmux window name using Python

Tags: python, fabric, tmux

Is there a way to change the `tmux` window title from python. I am using `fabric` to automate the deployment of long-running jobs, so I can run the jobs in the detached mode in `tmux`. (it may not be `fabric` related question, but I think people who have used fabric might have come across this problem) I understand that something like below can be used to create a new session and run commands in those sessions.

```
with Connection("ip") as cxn:
    cxn.run("tmux new -d -s session_name")
    cxn.run("tmux send -t session_name.0 ls ENTER")
```

Is there a way to create a new window with a specific title and call it like this:

```
with Connection("ip") as cxn:
  if cxn.run("tmux has -t session_name", warn=True, hide="err").exited != 0:
     cxn.run("tmux new -d -s session_name")
  cxn.run("tmux new -d -s session_name -n windown_name")
  cxn.run("tmux send -t session_name.window_name ls ENTER")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want but this will create a new session named "dev" and inside that session it will create a window title "win1" and launch `python` repl in that window.

```
with Connection("ip") as cxn:
    cxn.run('''tmux new-session  -s "dev" -n "win1" \; send-keys 'python'  C-m  \;''')
```

Comment: It seems like tmux doesn't identify any window with the name - `session_name.window_name`. It only has the concept of window numbers. Window titles are not used for reference but for users to be able to identify windows.

Answer (score 0):

The way that tmux references the window names is by colon-`:` so this works now -

```
with Connection("ip") as cxn:
  if cxn.run("tmux has -t session_name", warn=True, hide="err").exited != 0:
     cxn.run("tmux new -d -s session_name")
  cxn.run("tmux new-window -t session_name -n windown_name")
  cxn.run("tmux send -t session_name:window_name ls ENTER")
```

Without the complete knowledge of how `tmux` works, it is hard to workout such details. After reading the tutorial on [scripting tmux here](https://leanpub.com/the-tao-of-tmux/read#scripting-tmux) and digging into the code of `libtmux` [here](https://github.com/tmux-python/libtmux/blob/master/libtmux/session.py#L230) (python library to control `tmux`) I figured that `:` should be the thing to use and its working for me.